# Getting the "name" of a parent panel from a child control

Tags: c#, xaml

I have one static, and one dynamic set of buttons in two stack panels. I want to get the name of the stack panel of the button clicked. I don't want the type, I want the specific name. Is there a way to do that in C#??

Comment: ...curious, what does `xaml` have to do with getting the name of a parent control?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
private ButtonClick(object sender)
{
    string parent_name = ((Button)sender).Parent.Name;
}
```

or for WPF:

```
private ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement parent=(FrameworkElement)((Button)sender).Parent;
    string parent_name = parent.Name;            
}
```

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, I've just edited my example, hope it's better :)

Comment: Thank you Marco, i think it will help me a lot in my program. :)